# Visualizing regression in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using tensorflow for regression of a single scalar variable `y`. Is there a way to use tensorboard to visualize the regression in the form of a point cloud, one axis being the ground truth and the other being the estimate?

Comment: I'm afraid not - but why tensorboard? matplotlib gives you plenty of tools to do that

Comment: I suppose most of tensorboard's features could be implemented with matplotlib. However I find tensorboard very useful, and I use it. I would of course rather keep all of my visual summariers in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorboard has the ability to show images. So a solution is to plot the graph in matplotlib, rendering it as a PNG image and importing the result in tensorboard.

The topic is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38543850/1735003) and its answers.