# How to display custom images in TensorBoard using Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm working on a segmentation problem in Keras and I want to display segmentation results at the end of every training epoch.

I want something similar to [*Tensorflow: How to Display Custom Images in Tensorboard (e.g. Matplotlib Plots)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543850/tensorflow-how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-e-g-matplotlib-plots), but using Keras. I know that Keras has the [`TensorBoard`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) callback but it seems limited for this purpose.

I know this would break the Keras backend abstraction, but I'm interested in using TensorFlow backend anyway.

Is it possible to achieve that with Keras + TensorFlow?

Comment: This not your Answer, rather I have question, are you following any tutorial for Segmentation for Images on Keras or Tensorflow ?? Any Source or reference would be helpful ! Thanks in Advance

Comment: @ShivamKotwalia check this: https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation

Comment: Hi Fabio! Did you find a way to solve this problem? I would be interested by knowing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Rouky Not really, but it's possible to use callbacks to save temporary images in a directory. Of course a TensorBoard solution would be better, but I didn't try after using this workaround, which was enough for me.

Comment: @Fabio Ok thanks! I found how to display images in tensorboard but I get one line per epoch and per prediction (that makes a lot!)... instead of one line per image with a slider to choose the epoch... Not yet perfect...

Comment: @RomaneG you probably missed the 'tag' attribute. Check my answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

So, the following solution works well for me:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def make_image(tensor):
    """
    Convert an numpy representation image to Image protobuf.
    Copied from https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch/
    """
    from PIL import Image
    height, width, channel = tensor.shape
    image = Image.fromarray(tensor)
    import io
    output = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(output, format='PNG')
    image_string = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return tf.Summary.Image(height=height,
                         width=width,
                         colorspace=channel,
                         encoded_image_string=image_string)

class TensorBoardImage(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, tag):
        super().__init__() 
        self.tag = tag

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # Load image
        img = data.astronaut()
        # Do something to the image
        img = (255 * skimage.util.random_noise(img)).astype('uint8')

        image = make_image(img)
        summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag=self.tag, image=image)])
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs')
        writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
        writer.close()

        return

tbi_callback = TensorBoardImage('Image Example')
```

Just pass the callback to `fit` or `fit_generator`.

Note that you can also run some operations using the `model` inside the callback. For example, you may run the model on some images to check its performance.

[image: screen]

Comment: Awesome! That's approximately what I ended up doing (with a call to the model in the callback as you say), but inheriting from the existing keras Tensorboard callback. In fact creating another tensorboard callback for this purpose is a very good idea! Thank you for taking the time to write this code, I am sure it will be useful to many people.

Comment: `img = data.astronaut()` gives me an error: where exactly does `data` come from? I'm trying to use `X_train` and `Y_train` as the images.

Comment: @payne It's from http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.data.html#skimage.data.astronaut.

Comment: @FábioPerez my question was more about how do I obtain my `x_train` and `y_train` data (the input and corresponding ground truth) from within the `on_epoch_end` method.

Comment: @payne you can pass it as a member of your model, which is readable inside the callback.

Comment: `model.something` : what would be the `something`? Also, how do I get the outputs of the network as images?

Comment: how to obtain `y_true`, `y_pred` inside `on_epoch_end`?

Comment: To get validation data in the callback, use the `model.validation_data`. If the input are images and labels, then you can visualize e.g. the first image by taking `images = self.validation_data[0] # 0 - data; 1 - labels` and then `img = (255 * images[0]).astype('uint8')`. This is then passed to the `make_image` function as in the answer.

Comment: @FábioPerez If you pass `x_train` and `y_true` as member of the model, they are tensors not executed protobufs.

Comment: I had this error when using this code: `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type`.
This is coming up because my images are float dtype, the following is the fix I used to make it work:`tensor = img_as_ubyte( (tensor - tensor.min()) / (tensor.max() - tensor.min()))` with `from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte`.

Comment: Has anyone else used this callback together with a canonical `TensorBoard` callback? I am getting no output from my original tensorboard callback when I use it with this callback.

Comment: I tried to fix it using `filename_suffix` and defining the `FileWriter` only once in `set_model`, but now I have only the first 9 images of my training (over 500 epochs when testing).

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi did you find a way of solving your issue?

Comment: Yes I just put the images in a subfolder. Kind of a hack but it works for me.

Comment: @SimonFojtu when I tried your suggestion, I get `AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'validation_data'`. Have things changes for TF2.x?

Answer (score 11):

Based on the above answers and my own searching, I provide the following code to finish the following things using TensorBoard in Keras:

---

- problem setup: to predict the disparity map in binocular stereo matching;
- to feeds the model with input left image `x` and ground truth disparity map `gt`;
- to display the input `x` and ground truth 'gt', at some iteration time;
- to display the output `y` of your model, at some iteration time.

---

1. First of all, you have to make your costumed callback class with `Callback`. 
   `Note` that a callback has access to its associated model through the class property `self.model`. Also `Note`: **you have to feed the input to the model with feed_dict, if you want to get and display the output of your model.**

   ```
   from keras.callbacks import Callback
   import numpy as np
   from keras import backend as K
   import tensorflow as tf
   import cv2

   # make the 1 channel input image or disparity map look good within this color map. This function is not necessary for this Tensorboard problem shown as above. Just a function used in my own research project.
   def colormap_jet(img):
       return cv2.cvtColor(cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(img), 2), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

   class customModelCheckpoint(Callback):
       def __init__(self, log_dir='./logs/tmp/', feed_inputs_display=None):
             super(customModelCheckpoint, self).__init__()
             self.seen = 0
             self.feed_inputs_display = feed_inputs_display
             self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir)

       # this function will return the feeding data for TensorBoard visualization;
       # arguments:
       #  * feed_input_display : [(input_yourModelNeed, left_image, disparity_gt ), ..., (input_yourModelNeed, left_image, disparity_gt), ...], i.e., the list of tuples of Numpy Arrays what your model needs as input and what you want to display using TensorBoard. Note: you have to feed the input to the model with feed_dict, if you want to get and display the output of your model. 
       def custom_set_feed_input_to_display(self, feed_inputs_display):
             self.feed_inputs_display = feed_inputs_display

       # copied from the above answers;
       def make_image(self, numpy_img):
             from PIL import Image
             height, width, channel = numpy_img.shape
             image = Image.fromarray(numpy_img)
             import io
             output = io.BytesIO()
             image.save(output, format='PNG')
             image_string = output.getvalue()
             output.close()
             return tf.Summary.Image(height=height, width=width, colorspace= channel, encoded_image_string=image_string)


       # A callback has access to its associated model through the class property self.model.
       def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs = None):
             logs = logs or {} 
             self.seen += 1
             if self.seen % 200 == 0: # every 200 iterations or batches, plot the costumed images using TensorBorad;
                 summary_str = []
                 for i in range(len(self.feed_inputs_display)):
                     feature, disp_gt, imgl = self.feed_inputs_display[i]
                     disp_pred = np.squeeze(K.get_session().run(self.model.output, feed_dict = {self.model.input : feature}), axis = 0)
                     #disp_pred = np.squeeze(self.model.predict_on_batch(feature), axis = 0)
                     summary_str.append(tf.Summary.Value(tag= 'plot/img0/{}'.format(i), image= self.make_image( colormap_jet(imgl)))) # function colormap_jet(), defined above;
                     summary_str.append(tf.Summary.Value(tag= 'plot/disp_gt/{}'.format(i), image= self.make_image( colormap_jet(disp_gt))))
                     summary_str.append(tf.Summary.Value(tag= 'plot/disp/{}'.format(i), image= self.make_image( colormap_jet(disp_pred))))

                 self.writer.add_summary(tf.Summary(value = summary_str), global_step =self.seen)
   ```
2. Next, pass this callback object to `fit_generator()` for your model, like:

   ```
      feed_inputs_4_display = some_function_you_wrote()
      callback_mc = customModelCheckpoint( log_dir = log_save_path, feed_inputd_display = feed_inputs_4_display)
      # or 
      callback_mc.custom_set_feed_input_to_display(feed_inputs_4_display)
      yourModel.fit_generator(... callbacks = callback_mc)
      ...
   ```
3. Now your can run the code, and go the TensorBoard host to see the costumed image display. For example, this is what I got using the aforementioned code: [image]

   ---

   Done! Enjoy!

Comment: what is the code of this function  `some_function_you_wrote()`. How did you handle the batch dimension ? I get an error because the model accept a 4-D tensor not 3D-tensor! For me this fucntion `some_function_you_wrote()` return a numpy array of rgb image 3D dimension!

Comment: What would `tf.Summary.Image(height=height, width=width, colorspace= channel, encoded_image_string=image_string)` be in Tensorflow 2?

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to display matplotlib plots to the tensorboard (useful incases of plotting statistics, heatmaps, etc). It can be used for the general case also.

```py
class AttentionLogger(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def __init__(self, val_data, logsdir):
            super(AttentionLogger, self).__init__()
            self.logsdir = logsdir  # where the event files will be written 
            self.validation_data = val_data # validation data generator
            self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.logsdir)  # creating the summary writer

        @tfmpl.figure_tensor
        def attention_matplotlib(self, gen_images): 
            '''
            Creates a matplotlib figure and writes it to tensorboard using tf-matplotlib
            gen_images: The image tensor of shape (batchsize,width,height,channels) you want to write to tensorboard
            '''  
            r, c = 5,5  # want to write 25 images as a 5x5 matplotlib subplot in TBD (tensorboard)
            figs = tfmpl.create_figures(1, figsize=(15,15))
            cnt = 0
            for idx, f in enumerate(figs):
                for i in range(r):
                    for j in range(c):    
                        ax = f.add_subplot(r,c,cnt+1)
                        ax.set_yticklabels([])
                        ax.set_xticklabels([])
                        ax.imshow(gen_images[cnt])  # writes the image at index cnt to the 5x5 grid
                        cnt+=1
                f.tight_layout()
            return figs

        def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):  # when the training begins (run only once)
                image_summary = [] # creating a list of summaries needed (can be scalar, images, histograms etc)
                for index in range(len(self.model.output)):  # self.model is accessible within callback
                    img_sum = tf.summary.image('img{}'.format(index), self.attention_matplotlib(self.model.output[index]))                    
                    image_summary.append(img_sum)
                self.total_summary = tf.summary.merge(image_summary)

        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs = None):   # at the end of each epoch run this
            logs = logs or {} 
            x,y = next(self.validation_data)  # get data from the generator
            # get the backend session and sun the merged summary with appropriate feed_dict
            sess_run_summary = K.get_session().run(self.total_summary, feed_dict = {self.model.input: x['encoder_input']})
            self.writer.add_summary(sess_run_summary, global_step =epoch)  #finally write the summary!
```

Then you will have to give it as an argument to `fit/fit_generator`

```py
#val_generator is the validation data generator
callback_image = AttentionLogger(logsdir='./tensorboard', val_data=val_generator)
... # define the model and generators

# autoencoder is the model, note how callback is suppiled to fit_generator
autoencoder.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    callbacks=callback_image)
```

In my case where I'm displaying attention maps (as heatmaps) to tensorboard, this is the output.

[image: tensorboard]

Answer (score 2):

Similarily, you might want to try [tf-matplotlib](http://github.com/cheind/tf-matplotlib). Here's a scatter plot

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import tfmpl

@tfmpl.figure_tensor
def draw_scatter(scaled, colors): 
    '''Draw scatter plots. One for each color.'''  
    figs = tfmpl.create_figures(len(colors), figsize=(4,4))
    for idx, f in enumerate(figs):
        ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.scatter(scaled[:, 0], scaled[:, 1], c=colors[idx])
        f.tight_layout()

    return figs

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:

    # A point cloud that can be scaled by the user
    points = tf.constant(
        np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(100, 2)).astype(np.float32)
    )
    scale = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)        
    scaled = points*scale

    # Note, `scaled` above is a tensor. Its being passed `draw_scatter` below. 
    # However, when `draw_scatter` is invoked, the tensor will be evaluated and a
    # numpy array representing its content is provided.   
    image_tensor = draw_scatter(scaled, ['r', 'g'])
    image_summary = tf.summary.image('scatter', image_tensor)      
    all_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all() 

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log', sess.graph)
    summary = sess.run(all_summaries, feed_dict={scale: 2.})
    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=0)
```

When executed, this results in the following plot inside Tensorboard
[image]

Note that **tf-matplotlib** takes care about evaluating any tensor inputs, avoids `pyplot` threading issues and supports blitting for runtime critical plotting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a better way to log such custom images to tensorboard making use of the tf-matplotlib. Here is how...

```
class TensorBoardDTW(tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TensorBoardDTW, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dtw_image_summary = None

    def _make_histogram_ops(self, model):
        super(TensorBoardDTW, self)._make_histogram_ops(model)
        tf.summary.image('dtw-cost', create_dtw_image(model.output))
```

One just need to overwrite the _make_histogram_ops method from the TensorBoard callback class to add the custom summary. In my case, the `create_dtw_image` is a function that creates an image using the tf-matplotlib.

Regards,.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to draw landmarks on image:

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, generator):
        self.generator = generator
        self.model = model

    def tf_summary_image(self, tensor):
        import io
        from PIL import Image

        tensor = tensor.astype(np.uint8)

        height, width, channel = tensor.shape
        image = Image.fromarray(tensor)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(output, format='PNG')
        image_string = output.getvalue()
        output.close()
        return tf.Summary.Image(height=height,
                             width=width,
                             colorspace=channel,
                             encoded_image_string=image_string)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        frames_arr, landmarks = next(self.generator)

        # Take just 1st sample from batch
        frames_arr = frames_arr[0:1,...]

        y_pred = self.model.predict(frames_arr)

        # Get last frame for which we have done predictions
        img = frames_arr[0,-1,:,:]

        img = img * 255
        img = img[:, :, ::-1]
        img = np.copy(img)

        landmarks_gt = landmarks[-1].reshape(-1,2)
        landmarks_pred = y_pred.reshape(-1,2)

        img = draw_landmarks(img, landmarks_gt, (0,255,0))
        img = draw_landmarks(img, landmarks_pred, (0,0,255))

        image = self.tf_summary_image(img)
        summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(image=image)])
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs')
        writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
        writer.close()
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class customModelCheckpoint(Callback):
def __init__(self, log_dir='../logs/', feed_inputs_display=None):
      super(customModelCheckpoint, self).__init__()
      self.seen = 0
      self.feed_inputs_display = feed_inputs_display
      self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir)


def custom_set_feed_input_to_display(self, feed_inputs_display):
      self.feed_inputs_display = feed_inputs_display


# A callback has access to its associated model through the class property self.model.
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs = None):
      logs = logs or {}
      self.seen += 1
      if self.seen % 8 == 0: # every 200 iterations or batches, plot the costumed images using TensorBorad;
          summary_str = []
          feature = self.feed_inputs_display[0][0]
          disp_gt = self.feed_inputs_display[0][1]
          disp_pred = self.model.predict_on_batch(feature)

          summary_str.append(tf.summary.image('disp_input/{}'.format(self.seen), feature, max_outputs=4))
          summary_str.append(tf.summary.image('disp_gt/{}'.format(self.seen), disp_gt, max_outputs=4))
          summary_str.append(tf.summary.image('disp_pred/{}'.format(self.seen), disp_pred, max_outputs=4))

          summary_st = tf.summary.merge(summary_str)
          summary_s = K.get_session().run(summary_st)
          self.writer.add_summary(summary_s, global_step=self.seen)
          self.writer.flush()
```

Then you can call your custom callback and write the image in tensorboard

```
callback_mc = customModelCheckpoint(log_dir='../logs/',  feed_inputs_display=[(a, b)])
callback_tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='../logs/', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
callback = []
def data_gen(fr1, fr2):
while True:
    hdr_arr = []
    ldr_arr = []
    for i in range(args['batch_size']):
        try:
            ldr = pickle.load(fr2)           
            hdr = pickle.load(fr1)               
        except EOFError:
            fr1 = open(args['data_h_hdr'], 'rb')
            fr2 = open(args['data_h_ldr'], 'rb')
        hdr_arr.append(hdr)
        ldr_arr.append(ldr)
    hdr_h = np.array(hdr_arr)
    ldr_h = np.array(ldr_arr)
    gen = aug.flow(hdr_h, ldr_h, batch_size=args['batch_size'])
    out = gen.next()
    a = out[0]
    b = out[1]
    callback_mc.custom_set_feed_input_to_display(feed_inputs_display=[(a, b)])
    yield [a, b]

callback.append(callback_tb)
callback.append(callback_mc)
H = model.fit_generator(data_gen(fr1, fr2), steps_per_epoch=100,   epochs=args['epoch'], callbacks=callback)
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiye6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers here and elsewhere were an excellent starting point, but I found they needed some tweaking to work with Tensorflow 2.x and keras `flow_from_directory`*. This is what I came up with.

My aim was to verify the data augmentation process, so the images I have written to tensorboard are the augmented training data. That's not exactly what the OP wanted. They would have to change `on_batch_end` to `on_epoch_end` and access the model outputs (which is something I haven't looked into, but I'm sure it's possible.)

Similar to [Fabio Perez's answer with the astronaut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49363251/1295595), you will be able to scroll through the epochs by dragging the orange slider, showing differently augmented copies of each image that has been written to tensorboard. Careful with large datasets trained over many epochs. Since this routine saves a copy of every 1000th image in every epoch, you might end up with a large tfevents file.

the callback function, saved as `tensorflow_image_callback.py`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math

class TensorBoardImage(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, logdir, train, validation=None):
        super(TensorBoardImage, self).__init__()
        self.logdir = logdir
        self.train = train
        self.validation = validation
        self.file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs):
        images_or_labels = 0 #0=images, 1=labels
        imgs = self.train[batch][images_or_labels]

        #calculate epoch
        n_batches_per_epoch = self.train.samples / self.train.batch_size
        epoch = math.floor(self.train.total_batches_seen / n_batches_per_epoch)

        #since the training data is shuffled each epoch, we need to use the index_array to find something which uniquely 
        #identifies the image and is constant throughout training
        first_index_in_batch = batch * self.train.batch_size
        last_index_in_batch = first_index_in_batch + self.train.batch_size
        last_index_in_batch = min(last_index_in_batch, len(self.train.index_array))
        img_indices = self.train.index_array[first_index_in_batch : last_index_in_batch]

        #convert float to uint8, shift range to 0-255
        imgs -= tf.reduce_min(imgs)
        imgs *= 255 / tf.reduce_max(imgs)
        imgs = tf.cast(imgs, tf.uint8)

        with self.file_writer.as_default():
            for ix,img in enumerate(imgs):
                img_tensor = tf.expand_dims(img, 0) #tf.summary needs a 4D tensor
                #only post 1 out of every 1000 images to tensorboard
                if (img_indices[ix] % 1000) == 0:
                    #instead of img_filename, I could just use str(img_indices[ix]) as a unique identifier
                    #but this way makes it easier to find the unaugmented image
                    img_filename = self.train.filenames[img_indices[ix]]
                    tf.summary.image(img_filename, img_tensor, step=epoch)
```

integrate it with your training like this:

```
train_augmentation = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,
                                                                    shear_range=10,
                                                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                                                    brightness_range=[0.8, 1.2],
                                                                    horizontal_flip=False,
                                                                    vertical_flip=False
                                                                    )
train_data_generator = train_augmentation.flow_from_directory(directory='/some/path/train/',
                                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                shuffle=True
                                                                )

valid_augmentation = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
valid_data_generator = valid_augmentation.flow_from_directory(directory='/some/path/valid/',
                                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                shuffle=False
                                                                )
tensorboard_log_dir = '/some/path'
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=tensorboard_log_dir, update_freq='batch')
tensorboard_image_callback = tensorflow_image_callback.TensorBoardImage(logdir=tensorboard_log_dir, train=train_data_generator, validation=valid_data_generator)

model.fit(x=train_data_generator,
        epochs=n_epochs,
        validation_data=valid_data_generator, 
        validation_freq=1,
        callbacks=[
                    tensorboard_callback,
                    tensorboard_image_callback
                    ])
```

*I later realised that `flow_from_directory` has an option `save_to_dir` which would have been sufficient for my purposes. Simply adding that option is much simpler, but using a callback like this has additional features of displaying the images in Tensorboard, where multiple versions of the same image can be compared, and allowing the number of saved images to be customised. `save_to_dir` saves a copy of every single augmented image, which quickly adds up to a lot of space.