# How to write images to TensorBoard from Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am working on a segmentation problem in Keras, and I would like to see my model predictions. How do I make that happen? I looked at `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` and it has all the necessary data, but I cannot figure out how to add my images to a summary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display custom images in TensorBoard using Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784921/how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-using-keras)