# Extending Keras TensborBoard callback to visualize model predictions

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, tensorboard

When training deep semantic segmentation models, it is often convenient to visualize a sample of predictions on the validation set during the training. Right now I'm simply saving some predictions to disk on my training server. I'm looking to migrate this task to TensorBoard. Simply put, I wan't to visualize a set of predictions (say 5) over each epoch.

I know there is a simple way to do it in pure TensorFlow like `tf.summary.image(..)` but I don't see any easy way to incorporate this into the Keras TensorBoard callback.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabio Perez provided an answer which should do exactly what you're looking for here [How to display custom images in TensorBoard using Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784921/how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-using-keras?rq=1)